# TinyMCE: wordcount plugin is not counting special characters as word

Tags: tinymce

I have added the plugin wordcount to count the number of words entered in my TinyMCE texteditor.

```
plugins: "wordcount",
wordcount_cleanregex: /[.(),;:!?%#$?\x27\x22_+=\\/\-]*/g
```

It is counting letters and numbers but when I am giving a special character , it is not counting them.

```
for e.g ----
Hi I am 18 year old     (for this it is giving me count 6)
Hi I am ## year old     (for this it is giving me count 5)
```

Any idea what I need to do. I tried to remove:

```
    %#$ from wordcount_cleanregex , but it didn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the `wordcount_cleanregex` setting but rather with the `wordcount_countregex` setting:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/wordcount/#wordcount_countregex

If you look at the default one you will see why its skipping the characters that it is.  Here is the exact regex:

https://regex101.com/r/wL4fL1/1

If you tweak that regex you can get it to count your `##` as a word.

**Note**: There is some core cleaning that is done within the `wordcount` plugin that is done regardless of your configuration settings.  In TinyMCE 4.4.1 it looks like this:

```
    if (tx) {
        tx = tx.replace(/\.\.\./g, ' '); // convert ellipses to spaces
        tx = tx.replace(/<.[^<>]*?>/g, ' ').replace(/&nbsp;|&#160;/gi, ' '); // remove html tags and space chars

        // deal with html entities
        tx = tx.replace(/(\w+)(&#?[a-z0-9]+;)+(\w+)/i, "$1$3").replace(/&.+?;/g, ' ');
        tx = tx.replace(cleanre, ''); // remove numbers and punctuation

        var wordArray = tx.match(countre);
        if (wordArray) {
            tc = wordArray.length;
        }
    }
```

...so some core things are still stripped from your content regardless of what you put in the `wordcount_cleanregex` and `wordcount_countregex`.  If you want to change this core behavior you will need to modify the plugin's source code.

Comment: Thanks for the information,
so I have checked that and replaced my code with this:
plugins: "wordcount paste",
             wordcount_cleanregex: /[]/g,
             wordcount_countregex: /[\S\u2019\x27\-\u00C0-\u1FFF]+/g,
but still it's not counting & > <

Comment: You need to include the characters you want in your countregex - you are not including them in your regex.  You can use that regex101 site to play with your regex to get it right for what you need.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on regex101, it is counting & but I don't know why it's not counting for the editor.

Comment: Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle with your exact setup?

Comment: That wordcount regex does not have any of the characters `&` or`<` or `>` in the regex - so of course it won't include those characters.  Please see this updated fiddle that includes the characters you want in the regex:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Y5faab/1

Comment: Hey , It is still not counting & > < .. just try to give a seprate & or &&& or > or >>> or < or <<<

Comment: hey..so I have tried to look into this but unable to solve the issue, but I have written my own javascript function to count the words, is there a way I can add a variable on TinyMCE status bar and capture this function or wordcount from my Function on that variable which I will add on statusbar?

Comment: Sure you can ... just copy the plugin that comes with TinyMCE and replace its counting logic with your own.  Then load your plugin and not the original one.

Comment: So I have not downloaded anything from TinyMCE, I am just using the webURL of tinymce to fetch all the properties

Comment: Download TinyMCE and create a new wordcount plugin.  Then use the `external_plugins` configuration option to reference your code.  You can still use the CDN version for everything else.

Comment: ok great, so do I need to make changes in Wordcount.js or wordcount.min.js or in both ? and in reference link which File I need to link to ? .js or min.js ?

Comment: When you use the `external_plugins` approach you provide TinyMCE the URL to your plugin so you can call it whatever you like.  If your plugin code is small minifying will do little to change the load time.

Comment: So I added this:  external_plugins: {
                 "wordcount": "~/App_Data/plugin.js"
             }  and after this when I am running my application, it has turned TinyMCE editor to a normal text area

Comment: hey I posted my answer, can you look into that.

Answer (score 0):

here is my wordcount plugin which I am adding externally , The function getCount returns the number of words perfectly when I run this function seprately on my .aspx page as javascript function, but when I am running under this plugin it is only counting letters (it is not counting any number/special characters)

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('wordcount', function(editor) {

function update() {
    editor.theme.panel.find('#wordcount').text(['Words: {0}', getCount()]);
}

editor.on('init', function() {
    var statusbar = editor.theme.panel && editor.theme.panel.find('#statusbar')[0];

    if (statusbar) {
        tinymce.util.Delay.setEditorTimeout(editor, function() {
            statusbar.insert({
                type: 'label',
                name: 'wordcount',
                text: ['Words: {0}', getCount()],
                classes: 'wordcount',
                disabled: editor.settings.readonly
            }, 0);

            editor.on('setcontent beforeaddundo', update);

            editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        }, 0);
    }
});

getCount = function () {        
    var body = editor.getBody().innerHTML;
    text1 = body.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
    s = text1.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");//exclude  start and end white-space
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");//2 or more space to 1
    s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n"); // exclude newline with a start spacing
    return s.split(' ').length;

};
});
```